# formsource only in subform field type?

Tags: form, subform

So i need an XML form structure for a custom app that is used in different models.
The most logical approach would be to create an external XML form file containing that structure and include it in every XML model that requires it.

As far, I see using a `subform` with `formsource` attribute is the only ways to do that:

```
...
<field name="mystructure" type="subform" formsource="folder/to/custom/structure.xml" min="1" max="1" multiple="false" layout="joomla.form.field.subform.default" groupByFieldset="true" hiddenLabel="true" />
...
```

But i don't need all the mechanics behind the subform element, like repeating structures and so on. I only want to use one structure in multiple places.
I know this could also be accomplished, by doing it directly in the model, but i wanted to keep it as clean as possible, and that would create extra logic.

So is subform really the only way to use one external structure in different XML forms?

Comment: Is the structure the entire form in each model or are you wanting to add the fields from the structure to different forms?

Comment: It is a part of different forms in different models. They are using the same structure in different context.

Comment: Have you looked at writing a plugin which gets onContentPrepareForm, and then adding a section of xml to that form for the additional fields you want to introduce? (Basically the way that com_fields injects the custom fields).